# What is the best way to connect limbs to a seperate torso mesh in a rig?

Tags: mesh, rigging, objects, parent

I have a rig I'm working on, and all the limbs are separate meshes. I need the limbs to move along with the torso bones, though, and be like an anchor point to the other meshes. I am not sure the best way to go about this, however.

I think if I just use weight paint for the parts I could link it that way, but the only bones shown that I can edit the weight for are the separated bones.

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe join all the body parts together, and same thing for the armatures if there are different parts as well? Also maybe show a screenshot or even share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Ok, here's the file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=r0OABRRN" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/r0OABRRN/)

Comment: Joining everything will work for now, but I was also wondering if there was a way to do it without joining all the parts, as it just kinda makes everything else feel cluttered.

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense to keep separate parts imho, whether for the body or for the armature (even more for the armature), not sure what you mean by "it just kinda makes everything else feel cluttered"

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I just meant with stuff like shape keys being all together. Anywho, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Just joining all the parts together worked for me. :)

Comment: If you are planning to animate the character, you may find problems like armpits that have gaps to the trunk/torso of the character body.   Try putting the armature in the Pose mode and attempt any *extreme* poses that you may require, like an arm reaching over the head.  In this case you'll search and find (this forum) ways to add edges/surfaces in places like the base of an arm to the appropriate vertices of the torso.  This can be tedious but may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to have multiple armature objects for one character. It could perhaps make sense to have isolated objects if you had things like props from another file that needs to be independent. Basically, it's each "asset" its one rig.

**Before doing anything**: spend some time going through your bones and giving them real unique names, with `.L` and `.R` suffixes for bones that are symmetrical. Also, please do check the vertex groups names get updated accordingly. Not doing this now will cause issues with the rest of the procedure, good naming practice isn't just to look nice ;)

---

Here you can join your armatures into one quite simply. Select them all in object mode, finishing by the one of the spine, and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to join them into one object.

Now you need to also parent each limb parent to a common parent. The common for this is to parent the arms to the torso, and the legs to the hips. For this, select the future-children bones, then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> select the future-parent, and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > Parent Keep Offset (here you want to "keep the offset", otherwise the children would be snapped to their parent and made unable to move from there).

Finally, back in object mode, we need to make the limbs' mesh object follow the update. You can either select them, then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> select the torso mesh object and join them the same way you did for the armatures, Or if you want to keep them as separated objects you can just go through each limb object and update the name of the armature in the Armature Deform Modifier, which should be `Armature` if you joined them all like I described.

Bonus point:

If you need to export this rig, you should add a new bone at the base of the character, name it "root" and have it be the top parent of the whole bone hierarchy. It's a requirement for some export formats and softwares, and it's an easy way to move your character around in pose mode.